# Adding HTML Tags In JSX Data

Tags: javascript, html

Tring to create a blog that is imported from another file. Here's what it looks like.

```
blogs: [
    {
        _id: '5',
        title: "Example",
        text: "This is An example. I want to separate these two lines.",
    },
]
```

I'm unsure of how to place a tag between the two sentences. For example, I want it to be like

```
blogs: [
    {
        _id: '5',
        title: "Example",
        text: "This is An example. <br > I want to separate these <strong>two</strong> lines.",
    },
]
```

The result reads out in plain text

```
This is An example. <br > I want to separate these <strong>two</strong> lines.
```

I've tried several combinations of different quotes (single quote, double quotes, and backticks) and I cannot figure out the solution and googling has not helped much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the `text` into an element by getting rid of quotes, and wrapping it into an element. You can use any elements such as `div`, `React.Fragmenet` `(<>/)`.

```
{
    _id: '5',
    title: "Example",
    text: <>This is An example. <br /> I want to separate these <strong>two</strong>lines.</>,
}
```

Another way is to render it [dangerously](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). You should never do this unless you know what you are doing. I won't go further as this is probably not what you want.

Comment: No problem, I'm happy that it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use props **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** for that element

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: text}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) in case you don't want to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute.